# How to properly set up Sun's JDK?

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Oracle's JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6)

I'm trying to manually install the Sun JDK package (I have my reasons, don't bother asking why). I've successfully extracted the .bin file into /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_23, but the problem is the PATH variable.

I added this line to the /etc/environment file: `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_23"` and added `JAVA_HOME/bin` to the PATH variable, BUT the OS still doesn't recognise the command `java`, says it's not installed and offers me gcj and openjdk.

There was another way by using `java-package` and converting the .bin to .deb installer, but unfortunately that package is not available on/for maverick, so I can't do it that way.

How can I make the PATH variable work and is there anything else required apart from the environment variables to make it all work?
When I try to use the `update-java-alternatives -l` command, it says the following:
`awk: cannot open /usr/lib/jvm/*.jinfo (No such file or directory)

jdk1.6.0_23 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_23`
What should be the name of the file and the contents of it?

Comment: possible duplication - http://askubuntu.com/questions/21131/how-to-correctly-remove-openjdk-and-jre-and-set-the-system-use-only-and-only-sun