# How do I install Oracle JDK 6?

Tags: java, jdk

Most of the software is not thoroughly tested with Java 7 and I would like to install Oracle's JDK 6.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Could someone please provide me the instructions for the same?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Due to [license issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JavaTeam) Ubuntu will no longer distribute Oracle's JDK and JRE. Also previous versions supplied on PPAs suffer from security issues are are not recommended to be installed on any Ubuntu system.

There are no more supported [java releases from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) - Ubuntu officially supports OpenJDK and OpenJRE implementation of Java which is the base for Oracle's own implementation.

To install the OpenJDK & OpenJRE refer to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java).

The instructions below provide a guide to install the official Oracle JDK 6.  You will need to regularly update this manually to ensure your installation maintains recommended security and stability fixes.

## Install the Oracle JDK 6

> Oracle JDK 6 is no longer maintained. It is not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.
> You can however still download them from the [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)

Oracle themselves have the [official guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-self-extracting-138783.html) to install their JDK - below is based upon those instructions.

- [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the 32bit or 64bit Linux "compressed binary file" - it has a ".bin" file extension
- Give it permissions to execute and extract it

  `chmod a+x [version]-linux-i586.bin`

  `./[version]-linux-i586.bin`

During installation it will ask you to register - press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  Firefox will open with the registration page.  Registration is optional.

JDK 6 package is extracted into `./jdk1.6.0_x` directory, for example `./jdk1.6.0_30`.

Lets rename it:

```
mv jdk1.6.0_30 java-6-oracle
```

- Now move the JDK 6 directory to `/usr/lib`

`sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm`

`sudo mv java-6-oracle /usr/lib/jvm`

## switch to Oracle JDK 6

*[webupd8.googlecode.com](http://code.google.com/p/webupd8/downloads/list?can=2&q=&sort=filename%20uploaded&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount)* hosts a nice-easy script to help with this.

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/webupd8/update-java-0.5b
chmod +x update-java-0.5b
sudo ./update-java-0.5b
```

*don't worry - 0.5b refers to the script version - not the version of java!*

An alternative to this is to use the [webupd8 ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+index?batch=75&memo=150&start=150) and the `update-java` package.

[image]

Finally test the switch has been successful:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

These should display the oracle version installed - 1.6.0_30

### [Install the Firefox/Chrome plugin](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java)

In a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.mozilla/plugins
```

Remove the IcedTea plugin, if it has been installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove icedtea6-plugin
```

Remove a former version of the Java plugin (may or may not be present)

```
rm ~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so
```

Now you can install the plugin, by creating a symbolic link (you tell Firefox, where the plugin is located).

(32bit)

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

(64bit)

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Confirm that the JRE has been successful by using the [official oracle website](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp).

---

Linked Questions:

1. [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)
2. [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)
3. [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

Comment: nice and easy :)

Comment: @MPi - I would also echo Brunos comment - there is no longer a "sun" or an "oracle" package '/usr/lib/jvmc is where all the other implementations of java will go, besides, the naming of the folder where we are keeping oracle's jdk is custom, no package will overwrite it, and if it does there will be no problem since it will do the same as it was done here. there is really no reason what so ever that this is not close to a system wide installation of oracle's jdk. if you have any further suggestions please do so, but there is nothing wrong with the paths used here

Comment: @fossfreedom the plugin part works for me!!

Comment: The update-java package/script does not seem to contain oracle packages anymore, but one can use "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java" and "sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer"

Comment: Before the step about `webupd8`, make sure that `gksu` is installed on your system.

Comment: The `.bin` files seem unavailable on the Oracle site now. :(

Comment: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer` answer (currently below) is way better (now).

Comment: just followed your tutorials to make a build server for Android KitKat, which has Ubuntu 12-04.
It worked perfectly. You should also mention how to register $JAVA_HOME and $JRE_HOME and update the $PATH variable

Comment: java -version doesn't show java 6 oracle version at the end. But The @Bruno 's solution worked

Answer (score 54):

The reason why Oracle's Java implementation is not supported or distributed by Ubuntu already discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java).

The basic idea is that Oracle's Java Se will not be included in any official Ubuntu repo due to license problems created by Oracle.

That does not stop you from installing Oracle's JDK from a PPA or from the official package files from the Oracle's site.

This guide describes how-to download, install and make `java`, `javac` and `javaws` from Oracle available to use in your system.

#### How to install Oracle Java JDK6u30 on Ubuntu 11.10

(should work with any other version downloaded from Oracle)

- **Download Sun/Oracle Java JDK**

Download Sun/Oracle Java JDK or JRE from here (current version is JDK 6 Update 30) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

Note: Select any of the ***Linux x86*** or ***Linux x64*** bin packages (example `jdk-6u30-linux-i586.bin`, `jdk-6u30-linux-x64.bin`) depending on your system and preference.

- **Make the file executable**

`chmod +x /path/to/file/jdk-6u30-linux-*.bin`

- **Run Sun/Oracle Java JDK binary and delete it**

`/path/to/binary/jdk-6u30-linux-*.bin && rm /path/to/binary/jdk-6u30-linux-*.bin`

There will be a newly created folder on the same path with the extracted files

- **Move the folder to a system wide path and give it a more identifiable name**

```
mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
cd /path/to/binary/
mv /path/to/binary/jdk1.6.0_30 /path/to/binary/java-6-oracle && mv /path/to/binary/java-6-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/
```

- **Add the new version of java, javac and javaws as an system alternative and give it priority 1**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/javaws" 1
```

- **Select the new alternatives to be used**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select your created `java` alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Select your newly created `javac` alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Select your new created `javaws` alternative

- **Test your newly added `java` and `javac`**

`java -version` should return

```
java version "1.6.0_30"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.5-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and `javac -version` should return

```
javac 1.6.0_30
```

- **Update system paths**

Open `/etc/profile` with you favorite text editor, ie

> gksudo gedit /etc/profile

Navigate to the end of the file and add these contents

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
JAVA_BIN=$JAVA_HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_BIN
export JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_BIN
export PATH
```

Reload your system wide PATH `/etc/profile` with

```
. /etc/profile
```

That is for Oracle's JDK, `java`, `javac` and `javaws` should be running from the Oracle's package.

The version here installed can be updated easily by copying the new version over the currently installed files. Just extract the package and copy over the new one over the one that is currently installed.

You might want to check /etc/alternatives for links to older installs of JRE - there are many tools that might not be found on your system after a manual install like this.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to put the JDK under /usr/lib. It is a bad idea to put anything there by yourself, this area is expected to be handled by the packaging system.

Comment: @MPi there is no longer a "sun" or a "oracle" pacakage '/usr/lib/jvmc is where all the other implementations of java will go, besides, the naming of the folder where we are keeping oracle's jdk is custom, no package will overwrite it, and if it does there will be no problem since it will do the same as it was done here. there is really no reason what so ever that this is not close to a system wide installation of oracle's jdk. if you have any further sugestions please do so, but there is nothing wrong with the paths used here.

Comment: There is no Oracle Java now, but there may be in the future. But this is beside the point. Locally installed software should not go into the folders that are handled by the packaging system. There is /opt or /usr/local for precisely this use case; see also http://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard

Comment: So when I follow your instructions `update-java-alternatives` does not see the newly installed Oracle JDK. Is there anyway to synchronize `update-java-alternatives` with `update-alternatives`?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon what release of Ubuntu are you using? I can test and fix it if necessary.

Comment: @BrunoPereira 12.04

Comment: There is a typo in the last update-alternatives command in the answer by @BrunoPereira. It should be: sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/javaws" 1 Currently it has `"java"` in the middle instead of the correct `"javaws"` Also, I think the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables should be se it `/etc/environment` instead of `/etc/profile`. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

Comment: The `.bin` files seem unavailable on the Oracle site now. :(

Comment: Worked at Ubuntu 18_4 bionic

Answer (score 6):

Open the terminal and execute below commands one by one. It will install JDk as well as JRE. No need to configure anything. It will take care of everything.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update
```

JDK 6 along with JRE

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

OR FOR JDK 7

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Once executed you can check, whether the Java and JDK is installed by `java -version`  and then `javac -version`

Answer (score 4):

Since Oracle Java has been removed from the repository, you will have to add a new repository like mentioned in [this article](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-sun-java-6-jrejdk-from-ppa-in-ubuntu-11-04). The repository described there has also packages for Oneiric.

**Note: It's important to *trust* the repository/ppa you're installing from.**

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

**This could do anything.**

So, if you trust the repository and developer below;

> Open up a terminal window under Application -> Accessories ->
>   Terminal, adding the ppa > by:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Then, install java jre:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jre-plugin
> ```
>
> Install Jdk by the command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There is very good page on official [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java). There you can find all recommended methods. I've used this [excellent automatic script](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6).

```
cd ~/
wget https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/raw/0.2.6/oab-java.sh -O oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

Script will build packages from source and place them in local repo, then they can be installed e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-fonts sun-java6-source
```

You can see all available packages in `/var/local/oab/deb`.

Remember to select the right version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

To setup everything else (like browser plugin, keytool, etc.) you can use this (it will be a long list!):

```
sudo update-alternatives --all
```

The script is a wrapper for [this Debian script](https://github.com/rraptorr/sun-java6), if you're curious ;)

Answer (score 2):

I expect, that the ppa of ferramroberto might not be working in the future, because repackaging of java is not allowed any more. Unfortunately what is not allowed for canonical is also not allowed for any other packager. So the solution mentioned above might be the only way (which is basically a wrapper for update-alternatives!):

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html

It is generally a good idea, to get an oracle account and get the java newsletter to be informed about software updates until a solution comes along the way for us ubuntu users to be informed about updates.

Comment: I follow up the instructions in the link above, so I actually follow this link: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html and it work, really easy, should try. Upvote

Answer (score 1):

In many cases it is not necessary to switch over to Oracle Java (or any other alternative version) completely. Many applications that require something other than the standard Java version can be started by explicitely calling the required Java VM:

```
<path to alternative JRE>/bin/java -jar <application>.jar
```

Perhaps JAVA_HOME should also be explicitely set before starting the application:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to alternative JRE>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following [instruction](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html) by downloading the jdk binaries directly from Oracle. The instructions apply for jdk6 also.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle now owns Sun, and has renamed it to Oracle Java. If you want to install the latest version of Java 6, you can download it here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The binary file is a self-extracting archive. Copy it to where you want to install it, e.g. `/opt/java`

Then create a link,

```
# update-alternatives /usr/bin/java java /opt/java/bin/java 0
```

Do the same for `javac` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
```

- If you get this error:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository command not found
  ```
- Then install it by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
  ```
- And then run that command again:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
  ```

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: This is not a good way to install Java, because that PPA only provides very old versions, which have major shortcomings including *serious security bugs*. Oracle changed the licensing terms for the proprietary Java JRE and JDK so that it cannot be freely redistributed in this way. So there's no PPA anymore that provides safe, up-to-date Java. A full explanation, with citations, of what version the PPA is able to provide and why, cannot fit into a comment. But if you post a new question about that and ping me here (with `@EliahKagan`), I'll try to answer it.