# Problem installing Netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: installation, netbeans

i downloaded Netbeans 7.0.1 from netbeans.com for Linux, but i couldn't open it, i tried   many applications but it didn't work, why?
it says it's not supported and some times it gives me errors,
netbeans downloaded file look like this:
`netbeans-7.0.1-ml-php-linux.sh`
how i'm supposed to open and install it on my Linux machine?

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE:** *JDK * is required for installing and running the *Java SE, Java EE and All NetBeans Bundles*.

[How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

[How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6)

[How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

[How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

---

**Install Netbeans**

2. Go to Netbeans [download page](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) and download the netbeans Linux (x86/x64) .sh installer file (like netbeans-7.0.1-ml-linux.sh).
3. Copy your Netbeans installer file to your Desktop.
4. Open Terminal.To open terminal click the Dash home from unity launcher.And type terminal in the search field.And click Terminal.
5. Type the below code in terminal and hit enter. `cd Desktop`
6. Then type below code in terminal and hit enter `sudo chmod +x netbeans-*` Type your ubuntu password if needed and press enter.
7. Then type below code and press enter `sudo ./netbeans-*`
8. And then install Netbeans from GUI installer window. After the successful installation,click the Dash home from unity launcher.And type netbeans in the search field.And click Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 to open.

---

**Related question** :

- [How to uninstall NetBeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76908/how-to-uninstall-netbeans/76912#76912)

Comment: You do NOT need to be super user to install Netbeans 7 (no need for sudo neither in 5 nor in 6), just change the destination folder to one you have write access during installation.

Comment: So how to update it to 7.4 or upper? I have to use proxy for updating it. Is there other PPAs for it?

Answer (score 2):

Just as a suggestion.. 
You dont need to add a repository to install JDK, netbeans works flawlessly with openjdk, which is always on the default repositories on Ubuntu.

just issue con a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

and then install netbeans as hhlp said.

Here is a full how-to: [Netbeans 7.0.1 installed but won't run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82949/netbeans-7-0-1-installed-but-wont-run/83094#83094)