# Where is Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Netbeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75549/how-do-i-install-netbeans)

I did some search and it appears that Netbeans IDE should be available through the Ubuntu repositories. But it's not!
I'm wondering if I'm mistaken by any chance and Netbeans were never inside the repos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember netbeans being in the repos, however for the sake of control over my development environment, at least in java world I always use the vendors packages, i.e. i download the netbeans zip-File (from [this download directory](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/7.1/final/zip/)) and link the appropriate scripts to `/usr/local/bin`.

I also download the Java SDK from Oracle (what with the funny choices of SDKs in Ubuntu), but that is another story...

Comment: It might be usefull to post your instructions on the main question instead of this one.