# is there a ppa for up to date netbeans installation on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ppa, netbeans, ide

I search for my question too much, but i didn't found any good answer.

I want to know is there any separate repository for installing and updating netbeans on ubutnu 14.04?

In the ubuntu 14.04 standard repositories, netbeans version is 7.0, in case that the 8.x version is released.

Answer (score 4):

Though I'm not sure on details, being quite new to Linux, Stack, and with the IDE selections on here, I believe the propper ppa is ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer as was sourced from [vajdics launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~vajdics/+archive/netbeans-installer).

To list out some sort of instruction.

1. Open the terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> )
2. Input "`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer`" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Input "`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netbeans-installer`" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
4. You'll be prompted again as to whether you would like to continue the installation, Just input "`Y`" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

That's it. I hope this dispels some problems others might be having. To be fair, I did cheat, I was using 13.10, but I've grown tired of looking up my issues only to be directed to older posts/solutions that are either out of date or pandering to Ubuntu's built in solutions(*universe*). I hope this solution is one that works with 12.04 and that it helps all who are stuck on this issue.

Comment: Thank you, The repository that you recommended is just for Ubuntu Susy,in spite of the face i asked my question for a repository in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, NetBeans is actually in the Ubuntu `universe` PPA, so it is accessible to anyone with an Ubuntu installation.

### Installing NetBeans

1. Open Terminal. This can be done by searching for it in your Dash and opening it or typing the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Copy-paste the `sudo apt-get install netbeans` into the Terminal window you just opened. This can be done by highlighting the text by dragging the mouse over it and either right-clicking it and selecting Copy or by typing the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then paste it into Terminal by right-clicking within the window and selecting Paste.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command.
4. If asked for it, type your password, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. If asked, press `y` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Let Terminal finish running the command, then open NetBeans from your Dash. At this point, it is safe to close the Terminal window.

### Updating NetBeans to the Latest Version

If it is necessary that you have the latest version of NetBeans, you should follow these instructions to update.

1. Open another Terminal session.
2. Copy-paste the command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rockclimb/netbeans1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> again when asked to.
3. If prompted for your password, type it and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Copy-paste the command `sudo apt-get update` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Copy-paste the command `sudo apt-get upgrade` and answer `y` if asked.
6. NetBeans is now up-to-date. At this point it is now safe to close Terminal.

(Unfortunately, ppa:rockclimb/netbeans1 no longer works)

### More Information

`apt-get` is the default package manager for Debian, on which Ubuntu is based. `apt-get install` can be used to install a package. Since NetBeans is in the `universe` repository, it's available to all Ubuntu installations by default, so all you need to do is run a simple `apt-get install` command with the argument `netbeans`.

Since NetBeans is installed in a directory other than `/home`, it is necessary you prefix it with `sudo`. This is because you don't own any directories other than your own (`/home/USER`) but `root` has access to all directories. The `sudo` argument tells Terminal to run your command as `root` so that it can enjoy the elevated permissions necessary to run.

Comment: Your answer is not my correct answer.I know that. I need a repository for installing netbeans version which is more near the newest version(now 7.4).

Comment: Thank you. The repository you've introduced is good but it just contain the 7.2 version of netbeans. Is there any newer?

Comment: 7.4 is the newest version. Here's a [link to the Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~rockclimb/+archive/netbeans) so you can see the packages available to you.

Comment: By the way. your ppa link is incorrect and the correct is: `ppa:rockclimb/netbeans1`. ;)

Comment: Thank you. @Dillmo But the new ppa you said is also contain netbeans 7.2.

Comment: 8 is out, but not via ppa, see their website

Answer (score 1):

Update for [XKAL's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/441483/500613), the [ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer](https://launchpad.net/~vajdics/+archive/netbeans-installer) is now available for 12.04 (or later) also.

**Note:** For those who use the latest version of ubuntu, an up-to-date version of netbeans is available in the `[universe]` repository.

Comment: Thank you, this is the better answer. the netbeans version is newer than other ppas.