# How to uninstall NetBeans?

Tags: uninstall, netbeans

Since I did not install NetBeans via the Software Center (I installed it as an .sh file) I can't see an easy way of uninstalling the program.

How can I safely uninstall the program?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I installed it with this command: chmod 777 /path/netbeans.sh

Answer (score 154, accepted):

1. There will be a file named `uninstall.sh` in `/usr/local/netbeans-x.x` if you installed netbeans with root privilege. If you installed it with a normal user account the `netbeans-X.X` folder will be in your home directory. (Here x.x refers to the version number such as `6.9` or `7.2` etc)
2. Open a terminal and go to netbeans' installation directory using `cd` command. Such as `cd /usr/local/netbeans-x.x`.
3. Use 'su' to become superuser  (type in your root password).
4. Then execute uninstall.sh file with the command `sh uninstall.sh`.

Alternatively, You can double click on it and choose "run in terminal" option. You need to supply the password (admin user's) to do this.

Comment: Note that you only need to be root if you installed using root. Otherwise running uninstall.sh without using su/sudo works fine.

Comment: The uninstaller wants to uninstall Tomcat too, but I want to keep it because it is used by the new installation of Netbeans I have already done.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Now, How to uninstall it without removing my settings and apply that settings to the new version of the netBeans (eg. 7.3 or 7.4) which i want to install instead?

Answer (score 49):

**To uninstall the IDE:**

- Shut down the IDE.
- Find the IDE installation directory :

  ```
  locate netbeans
  ```
- In the IDE installation directory, typically in your home directory there is a directory called netbeans. Once inside it, run the uninstaller:

  ```
  ./uninstall.sh
  ```
- At the Summary page, click Uninstall.
- After uninstallation completes, click Finish.

**To uninstall GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1**:

- Shut down the IDE.
- Locate the application server installation directory.

  ```
    Linux     root    /usr/local/glassfish-3.1
  ```

  - In  your home directory there is a director call glassfish look inside and you can find it, run the file :

    ```
    ./uninstall.sh
    ```
- At the Summary page, click Uninstall.
- After uninstallation completes, click Finish.

Source [here](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/install.html#uninstall_sollinux)

---

**Related Question :**

- [Problem installing Netbeans 7.0.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75401/problem-installing-netbeans-7-0-1/75410#75410)

Comment: What if he install netbeans with admin user account?

Answer (score 7):

Simply dragging and dropping the `uninstall.sh` from a home install folder to a terminal activates the netbeans uninstaller.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `~/netbeans x.x/` and execute `uninstall.sh` .

Also, if you installed glassfish or tomcat, look for their respective folders in ~/
and execute their uninstaller.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ok here's a more sophisticated process. Open synaptic and search for "nautilus execute". Install it.
2. Go to `/usr/local/netbeans` and find the `uninstall.sh` file.
3. Upon finding right click on it. You will now see a option "execute as" in the context menu. Select that and select "root".

Thats it. Now wait for some moment and the un-installation wizard will show up. Now follow the on screen dialogue.

Note: You need to delete `.nb`, `.netbeans`, `netbeans-derby` etc folders from your home folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confuse with codes. Here is the simplest way to **Uninstall** Netbeans..

Open *Files*.

Select *NetBeans-8.1Beta* (if you are using another version then select your version)

Open Terminal (alt+ctrl+T)

Drag uninstall.sh file to terminal window.

Uninstallation Process will be automatically intiated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old post, but i came here looking for how to remove version 7 as i have 8 installed. I have found that it can be removed from the dash.

Ubuntu 14.04: Dash -> search netbeans (You should see two icons if you have two versions installed) -> right click the version you want removing, a button should appear toward the bottom of the information that says uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd installed the netbeans through Ubuntu software center it is enough to use the same to uninstall it.
It is a very simple process. Go to Ubuntu software center and select the select the netbeans ide and uninstall it.

If it is installed via terminal, then locate the netbean directory normally(usr/local/netbean) and run the uninstall file uninstall.sh.

Answer (score 0):

If NetBeans is installed from a downloaded `netbeans.sh` file, you can uninstall from its directory like:

```
cd ~/netbeans-8.2/   # or your NetBeans version 
chmod a+x uninstall.sh
./uninstall.sh
```

---

*Otherwise*, to uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove netbeans
```

Uninstall with config:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge netbeans
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

If Universe repository in not allowed, enable it and update:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```