# What IDE for developing basic applications accessing MYSQL database?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a noob and want to develop fairly basic web applications accessing MYSQL database.

Any suggestions on what IDE to develop these applications that I can then host on a webserver provided by my webhost?

By the way, my webhost runs a 'Linux' server with Perl, Python, etc. There is no support for ASP.NET, etc.

Comment: I like phpMyAdmin, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/)

is an award-winning integrated development environment available for Windows, Mac, Linux, and Solaris. The NetBeans project consists of an open-source IDE and an application platform that enable developers to rapidly create web, enterprise, desktop, and mobile applications using the Java platform, as well as PHP, JavaScript and Ajax, Groovy and Grails, and C/C++.

[Connecting to a MySQL Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html)

[Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html)

NOTE :

- [How do I install Netbeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75549/how-do-i-install-netbeans)
- [Problem installing Netbeans 7.0.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75401/problem-installing-netbeans-7-0-1/75410#75410)
- [How to uninstall NetBeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76908/how-to-uninstall-netbeans/76912#76912)

Answer (score 1):

People usually use **eclipse** as an IDE on Ubuntu.
Install with Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or with terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

---

If you are developing Java based applications, then **netbeans** would be another option.
Install with Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or with terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i use [PDT: Eclipse PHP Development Tools](https://eclipse.org/pdt/).

But, there are still another good options out there, like [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/). If you have on commercial projects, please considering to buy commercial license too.