# uninstalling .sh files

Tags: scripts, uninstall, netbeans

I have been run this code `sudo ./uninstall.sh` in the the directory which I had been install netbeans 8.0.1 and the code runs and the uninstall window opens but it doesn,t uninstall anything.!! 
Is anybody here that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread: [How to uninstall NetBeans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76908/how-to-uninstall-netbeans?rq=1)

If that doesn't work:

Try looking for a readme or a help in the netbeans folder, and look for more information on uninstalling.

You also can run the command `gksudo nautilus`, which opens your file manager which can delete all files, even those which normally are read only.

Then go to other locations in that file manager, select computer (your hdd) and press ctrl+f and search for netbeans, delete any file that comes up, that you think is related to the program (check the last modified date, if you remember when you installed netbeans, you can easily do this by enabling a last modified column in your file manager)

Comment: Running `sudo nautilus` is a bad idea. See http://askubuntu.com/q/11760/15003.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that, i'll just change it to gksudo then.