# Netbeans doesn't start, Java fatal error, unless sudo

Tags: java, netbeans, crash

Fresh 13.10 64b

Openjdk 6 is there, I just installed Netbeans 7.01 from the repo, but it doesn't work, I open then a console

```
elect@elect-desktop:~$ netbeans 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007faebdf79325, pid=5251, tid=140388628424448
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu Saucy Salamander (development branch), package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu2
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgobject-2.0.so.0+0x14325]  g_cclosure_marshal_BOOLEAN__BOXED_BOXEDv+0x985
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/elect/hs_err_pid5251.log
[thread 140386948781824 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#
/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../platform/lib/nbexec: line 548:  5251 Aborted                 (core dumped) "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" -Djdk.home="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64" -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -classpath "/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar" -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy="DIRECT" -Dnetbeans.system_http_non_proxy_hosts="" -Dnetbeans.dirs="/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/nb:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../ergonomics:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/ide:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/java:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../xml:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/apisupport:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../webcommon:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../websvccommon:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../enterprise:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../mobility:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../profiler:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../ruby:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../python:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../php:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../visualweb:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../soa:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../identity:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../uml:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/harness:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../cnd:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../dlight:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../groovy:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../extra:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../javafx:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../javacard:" -Dnetbeans.home="/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform" '-Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade' '-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense' '-XX:MaxPermSize=384m' '-Xmx768m' '-client' '-Xss2m' '-Xms32m' '-XX:PermSize=32m' '-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true' '-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true' '-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true' '-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false' -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/home/elect/.netbeans/7.0/var/log/heapdump.hprof" org.netbeans.Main --userdir "/home/elect/.netbeans/7.0" "--branding" "nb" 0<&0
```

Looking around, the second answer, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82949/netbeans-7-0-1-installed-but-wont-run) Vigintas Labakojis, points out something regarding permission, I just try sudo netbeans, it works..

Then I look for the 
~/.cache/netbeans/

I dont have, I have instead

~/.netbeans/

Then I run his commands on those folder, it doesn't work..

It must be something else, do you have any idea?

In any case, my log /home/elect/hs_err_pid5251.log is [here](http://pastebin.com/YcVWBzda)

Comment: now use umake, which is ubuntu make, to install IDE's.  Perhaps the q is outdated now.

Comment: Of course it is, I was dealing with Ubuntu 13.10 and OpenJDK 6..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with the netbeans_jdkhome variable I had the feeling I didn't have the right java installed, so I installed it as described [here](http://hafsalrahman.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/oracle-java-installation-procedure-on-ubuntu-12-0412-1013-0413-10-and-linux-mint/) and then I modified the /etc/netbeans.conf

And then I solved, (i just had another warning saying that one file inside my ~/.netbeans, so I run nautilus with sudo and try to fix it again but graphically)

Ps: do NOT use the netbeans version from the repo, it is [broken](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-128168.html), better download the last and working one directly from the official site