# Netbeans won't open

Tags: 64-bit, java, netbeans

This is probably my own fault, I removed and reinstalled java on my computer, this is what happends:

```
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$ netbeans 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc3f78d5320, pid=2687, tid=140480869590784
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 13.10, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu2.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fc3f78d5320
[error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xb]

# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/jeggy/hs_err_pid2687.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#
/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../platform/lib/nbexec: line 548:  2687 Aborted                 (core dumped) "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" -Djdk.home="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64" -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -classpath "/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar" -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy="DIRECT" -Dnetbeans.system_http_non_proxy_hosts="" -Dnetbeans.dirs="/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/nb:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../ergonomics:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/ide:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/java:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../xml:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/apisupport:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../webcommon:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../websvccommon:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../enterprise:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../mobility:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../profiler:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../ruby:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../python:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../php:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../visualweb:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../soa:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../identity:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../uml:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/harness:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../cnd:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../dlight:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../groovy:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../extra:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../javafx:/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/bin/../javacard:" -Dnetbeans.home="/usr/share/netbeans/7.0.1/platform" '-Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade' '-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense' '-XX:MaxPermSize=384m' '-Xmx768m' '-client' '-Xss2m' '-Xms32m' '-XX:PermSize=32m' '-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true' '-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true' '-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true' '-Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false' -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/home/jeggy/.netbeans/7.0/var/log/heapdump.hprof" org.netbeans.Main --userdir "/home/jeggy/.netbeans/7.0" "--branding" "nb" 0<&0
jeggy@jeggy-XPS:~$
```

And then it creates this file in my home folder called [hs_err_pid2687.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6769134/)

**UPDATE:**
I've downloaded the installer from their [website](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) the one with everything included. and I then ran the installation file '*sudo sh ./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh*' and got this:

[image]

***I guess you should tell us how you uninstalled and reinstalled Java.***

I removed "OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime" and "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" and installed them again through the software center

[image]

Comment: I guess you should tell us how you uninstalled and reinstalled Java..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling - first remove it using this:

```
sudo apt-get remove netbeans
```

or this, but it will remove config files etc:

```
sudo apt-get purge  netbeans
```

then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**

As one bit in your answer seems to refer to openjdk 6, try version 7:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

But the error may be due to it not finding version 6, so do:

```
apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

There is a answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/75410/178596) that may also be of help.

Comment: I've already tried that, I more think it's something wrong with my Java. But Eclipse, BlueJ, Minecraft and java applications online do work fine :/

Comment: Try purging it as well, and moving any config files for it in your home directory.

Comment: I removed it and then deleted the .netbeans folder and then installed it again and same thing happened. And still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This got it working for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install netbeans-installer
```