# Sun's JDK on Ubuntu 11.10 Server Edition

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Oracle Java JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-6)

How do I install Sun's JDK6 on Ubuntu 11.10 on command line ?