# How to install a specific version of java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Oracle Java JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-6)

I want to install JDK 6u30 or later on ubuntu (but not java 7), how can I do so?

I'm on ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember I have installed it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre sun-java6-jdk
```

But here is the official way from Oracle how to do it: [jdk6_30 install](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-137561.html#linux)

Comment: this is for a server, so no GUI.