# How to set default Java version?

Tags: software-installation, java

I followed all the instructions stated at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/), but am encountering some problems with the last part of it.

I actually have version 6.22 of java and would like to update to version 6.30.

So after moving the extracted directory `java-6-oracle` into `/usr/lib/jvm` I do not know what to do, since the script that is pointed out in the answer above updates from java 5 to java 6.

For sake of clearness here is output if I do an `ls` in dir `/usr/lib/jvm`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm
total 8 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14 2011-07-12 15:18 default-java -> java-6-openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14 2011-07-12 12:19 java-1.6.0-openjdk -> java-6-openjdk 
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 2012-04-12 12:06 java-6.31-oracle 
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 2012-02-24 14:43 java-6-openjdk
```

What should I do now?

---

**ADDED PART**

Under the suggestion of @fossfreedom I ran the script anyway and actually it updated the java version.

In fact if I run command `java -version` output will be the following:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

There is **still a problem**, if Irun `javac -version` it gives me the old version installed:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_22
```

And if I use the tester at this [link](http://javatester.org/about.html) it will tell me that version is

```
Java Version 1.6.0_22 from Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

What's going wrong?

It seems that Java Runtime Environment has updated, but Java Compiler and Java plugin for browser have not.

How can I update them?

---

**OTHER ADDED PART**

`sudo update-alternatives --config java` will return following output

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6.31-oracle/bin/java     1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6.31-oracle/bin/java     1062      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

these makes sense with the fact that JRE is correctly updated to version 6.31, issues are on Java Compiler and Java browser plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: @fossfreedom I haven't tried it cause I thought it wasn't a good idea being it explicitely written for uploading from Java 5 to 6, should I anyway?

Comment: hmmm - possibly you may be confusing that the webupd8 script is 0.5b?  That is the version of the script - it doesnt refer to the java version.  Give it a try.  Lets see a screenshot of what the window looks like when you run the script.

Comment: @fossfreedom yeah that totally confused me ;D I ran the script! check the edits in question!thks a lot for helping me..

Comment: how very strange ... never encountered that.  Anyway - look at the answer just below - you should be able to `sudo update-alternatives` as per the example.

Comment: @fossfreedom updated again question!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3090/discussion-between-matteo-and-fossfreedom)

Comment: `javac --version` is for JDK whereas `java --version` is for JRE

Comment: @Matteo - answer updated - you'll need to follow the plugin installation directions as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6/89080#89080

Comment: @Ashu - javac --version is JavaCompiler and java --version is for JRE (i think)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477415/how-to-set-oracles-java-as-the-default-java-in-ubuntu/22392627

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Re your first question:

possibly you may be confusing that the webupd8 script is 0.5b. That is the version of the script - it doesnt refer to the java version.

Further to the setting of the javac version.

I suspect you need to explicitly give the path of the javac compiler

i.e.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6.31-oracle/bin/javac" 1
```

followed by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

---

With regards to setting up the java chrome plugin.

The master question:

[How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6/89080#89080)

includes this information - since your folder structure is slightly different your link command should be:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6.31-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/
```

Comment: On its own this just changes the compiler - see the answer below for update-java-alternatives which handles switching all of the java-related alternatives, which is 82 on my system.

Comment: 101% correct and perfect , i used this to perfect mine for java jdk 19 adesoji@adesoji-Lenovo-Legion-7-15IMH05:~$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-19/bin/javac" 1
and it worked

Answer (score 102):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35305363/1200764); run

```
sudo  update-java-alternatives --list
```

to list off all the Java installations on a machine by name and directory, and then run

```
sudo  update-java-alternatives --set [JDK/JRE name e.g. java-8-oracle]
```

to choose which JRE/JDK to use.

If you want to use different JDKs/JREs for each Java task, you can run update-alternatives to configure one java executable at a time; you can run

```
sudo  update-alternatives --config java[Tab]
```

to see the Java commands that can be configured (java, javac, javah, javaws, etc).  And then

```
sudo  update-alternatives --config [javac|java|javadoc|etc.]
```

will associate that Java task/command to a particular JDK/JRE.

You may also need to set JAVA_HOME for some applications: from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22392627/1200764) you can use

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

for JREs, or

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:jre/bin/java::")
```

for JDKs.

Comment: The first command needs no sudo :)

Answer (score 27):

I think you should take a look at the `update-java-alternatives` command from the `java-common` package and the `*.jinfo` files used by it. With that you should be able to switch completely between java installations (regardless of JDK, JRE, ...).

Comment: I tried the `update-java-alternatives` and then `java -version` was correct, but the link in `$JAVA_HOME` was still wrong... I changed that one manually, but I wonder whether there is something missing in the `update-java-alternatives` in that regard.

Answer (score 22):

On ubuntu/linux you can switch java version using

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

But before, you need install the version.

You can use this script (./install-java.sh) to install multiple JVMs

```
#!/bin/sh
(
lookforJdks=$PWD
echo "Directory: $lookforJdks"
jdks=`test -e ./javac || find $lookforJdks -type d -iname '*jdk1.*' 2> /dev/null`
#set -e
echo 'which jdk do you want to choose? looking for jdks. This might take a while'
echo "$jdks" | awk '{printf("%5d : %s\n", NR,$0)}'
read choose
test -e ./javac || cd `echo "$jdks" | tr '\n' ',' | cut -d',' -f $choose`/bin
for e in appletviewer extcheck idlj jar jarsigner java javac javadoc javah javap jconsole \
 jdb jhat jinfo jmap jps jrunscript jsadebugd jstack jstat jstatd native2ascii rmic \
 schemagen serialver wsgen wsimport xjc jvisualvm jmc; do sudo update-alternatives \
 --install /usr/bin/$e $e $(readlink -f ./$e) 100; done
)

echo "RUN update-alternatives --config java"
```

Put this script in folder where has unpacked the JVM(s), and run:

```
/opt/install-java.sh
```

Next use:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Why not use the software updater to install the various JDK/JREs?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to manualy set alternatives for javac javaws javadoc or any other java related commands, you might want to make them slaves of the java altenative.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java" 0 --slave "/usr/bin/javadoc" "javadoc" "/opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/javadoc"


update-alternatives: updating alternative /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java because link group java has changed slave links


:/opt/jdk1.8.0_74$ sudo update-alternatives --display java
```

java - auto mode
  link best version is /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java
  link currently points to /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave javadoc is /usr/bin/javadoc
/opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java - priority 0
  slave javadoc: /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/javadoc

Change /opt/jdk1.8.0_74/ with the dir where your jdk is installed.

Comment: This is what is needed.. a uniform way to switch Java versions... but there is a dance between update-alternatives and update-java-alternatives... that I don't quite see amongst all these answers going (like an octopus) in many different directions all at once leading to no general solution... we've come from versions 5 & 6 to 17 & 18.  Most of these answers won't oblige.

This answer is a good start.... combine with jinfo details and the dance between update-alternatives and update-java-alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you need, for example, to automatically switch to Java 8 (compiler 1.8), in an one-liner, for example for a script or continuous integration test suite, you can run

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s $(sudo update-java-alternatives -l | grep 8 | cut -d " " -f1) || echo '.'
```

It will automatically fetch any java 8 version available and set it using the command `update-java-alternatives`.

The `|| echo '.'` at the end just ensures the command returns success, because strangely `update-java-alternatives` by default returns error (1). You may skip it if you don't need this for a test suite.

If you want to switch to any other version just replace the `8` by the version you want in the previous command.

Answer (score 0):

Default java version used by Ubuntu system.
`update-alternatives --config java`

Default javac used by Ubuntu.
`update-alternatives --config javac`

Applications that use the environment variable $JAVA_HOME to find the java (jre or jdk) path.
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-20-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score -1):

Open `/etc/environment` in any your text editor and add the following line:

```
JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk
```

- Java path could be diffrent.
Use source to load the variables, by running this command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Then check the variable, by running this command:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

With this path set, run this command:

```
sudo  update-java-alternatives --list
```

Choose your default Java Version.

Comment: Sourcing /etc/environment also corrupts your PATH. ???