# How to set the default Java version

Tags: 11.10, java, update-alternatives

I have been using Java 6 on Ubuntu 11.10, but now I want to update to version 7. I've installed version 7 via PPA [as described here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html). If I run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I get the following output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   64        auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java      63        manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   64        manual mode
```

Similarly, if I run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

I get the output:

```
  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac   64        auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/javac      63        manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac   64        manual mode
```

So it looks like version 7 is already the default. But if I run either

```
java -version
```

or

```
javac -version
```

The output indicates that version 6 is still the default. How can I set the default to version 7?

Comment: Have a look at [Java](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

Comment: @Mitch thanks, but it just says to use `update-alternatives`, which I've already tried

Comment: did you `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default` and **reboot**?

Comment: FYI, 11.10 is End of Life.

Answer (score 4):

As per this answer: [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version/121673#121673)

Try providing the explicit path along with `update-alternatives --install` first, and then run `update-alternatives` to make your selection:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --config java

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `javac` too.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had sun jdk6 installed. After

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config java
    sudo update-alternatives --config javac
    sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

a restart was necessary for me. Than it worked.

**Edit:** I realized it was not enough to do the steps above.

I also had to edit the environment variable:

```
    sudo nano /etc/environment
```

And add (a different java version will require a different string) :

```
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

Answer (score 0):

insert the number that identifies the path you want and press enter. in this case insert 1.

finally, try to test the version `java -version`

Comment: I want version 7, not 6. The output of `update-alternatives` indicating that I'm already using version 7, but `java -version` shows that I'm still using version 6.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your java binary is pointing to somewhere other than `/etc/alternatives/java`.

Check the output of: `type java`

Does it say `/usr/bin/java`? If so, then check if that points correctly to alternatives:

`ls -l /usr/bin/java` should show it pointing to `/etc/alternatives/java`.

Lastly confirm that `/etc/alternatives/java` itself is pointing to java-7:
`ls -l /etc/alternatives/java`.

The update-alternatives command only adjusts the last one and assumes that default points to `/usr/bin/java` which in turn is correctly linked to `/etc/alternatives/java`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried nearly every methods listed above, but still found `java -version`  print the wrong version while `ls -al /etc/alternatives/java` already pointed to the right one.

So I run:  `which java`  and found that the result shows that I was using java from `/usr/local/jdk_xxx/bin/java`, then I deleted this folder and restarted the terminal. Now the java works well.

Hope it will help others.