# I recently updated to ubuntu 15.04, but Java won't open .jar files!

Tags: 15.04, java, files, minecraft, jar

I have got one thing to work though. By using this article:http://tipsonubuntu.com/2015/03/30/install-minecraft-in-ubuntu-15-04/  I have been able to open minecraft, but still nothing else is working How do I install minecraft?

Comment: to be clear MINECRAFT WORED it was other jar files that was the problem :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install java.

This command installs Java on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

To run Java applications in your browser:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

To run Minecraft, you'll need to install Orcale Java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: I had java, just i had installed it from the Ubuntu Software center, but this seems to work :D THANKS!

Comment: @CraigNelson No probs, glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

After what DevRobot mentioned you'll want to be sure you're using the right version of Java.

This tutorial might help: [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version)

```
java -version
```

Will tell you which version you're running.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Will let you select which version of java to use when you have multiple versions installed (open source v. oracle)

Comment: to be clear MINECRAFT WORED it was other jar files that was the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

If you already install java, you can try command line to start minecraft.

open the terminal in where the jar file is.

for e.g. my "program.jar" file is in Desktop folder.

```
cd Desktop
```

And then execute the command.

`java -jar program.jar`

Comment: to be clear MINECRAFT WORED it was other jar files that was the problem :P