# How do I undo the changes that oracle-java8-set-default makes?

Tags: java, jdk, oracle, software-uninstall

I've uninstalled java from my system using the steps listed here: https://askubuntu.com/a/185250

However there are still some left over oracle paths in my PATH variable. I think this has been caused by installing the `oracle-java8-set-default` package.

The parts of my PATH that I want to get rid of: `/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/jre/bin`

Does anyone know how I can remove these old entries from my PATH?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version has all the commands you will need.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/etc/profile.d` and you will see `jdk.csh` and `jdk.sh`. They are added by `oracle-java8-set-default`.