# Why is my java always set to: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Tags: oracle

I've installed (and tried to remove) some openjdk oracle installer set-default package and since then every time I open a new terminal I need to export my JAVA_HOME.

Even though it is set properly in my /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_162"

How can I get my java back?

Comment: OpenJDK and Oracle are both implementations of Java, and with each, you can install just the JRE or the JDK. You might want to edit your question to include--specifically--first, what you installed (you mention "some openjdk oracle installer set-default package" which doesn't make sense), and then, what you attempted to uninstall.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of ["How do I undo the changes that oracle-java8-set-default makes?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/934326/616451).

Comment: I did a grep oracle in the /etc folder, found a jdk.sh and a jdk.csh scripts.  Removed those and rebooted Ubuntu and I have my JAVA_HOME back