# Completely remove Java 9 from Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

did a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 installation a while ago and needed to install Java to build react-native apps on my PC. So I was able to install Java 9 in the manual way by downloading it from the Oracle official site.

Now when I run `java --version` I get

```
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

and when I run `javac --version` I get

```
javac 9.0.4
```

And then I followed official react docs and created a react app. Then when I try to run it on an android emulator I got an error and I opened a [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17688#issuecomment-359288357)

Seems like it's an issue with Java 9 . So now I need to completely remove java 9 from my PC and install Java 8. How can I completely remove Java 9 from my Ubuntu 17.10 .

P.S :

When I ran `sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk` it showed Java 9.
Then I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572573/cant-remove-java-in-ubuntu-16-04) and ran `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java9-*` and now there's nothing shows when I run `sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk`

Comment: You can have multiple Java versions installed alongside each other and select which Java version to use from the terminal. Why did you remove Java 9 because it didn't work with React instead of installing Java 8 alongside Java 9 and then selecting Java 8 as the default Java version by following the instructions at [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version)

Comment: Thanks @karel .
Anyway I followed [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and installed Java 8 and set it as default.

Answer (score 1):

You can run below snippet to completely remove Java 9. You will need only one java (10, 9 or 8 whatever you like). Simply, purge everything about java and install fresh one later.

```
 sudo apt purge java*
```

You might want to look at this thread as I uninstalled Java 9 and installed new Java 10. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507160/how-to-install-jdk-10-under-ubuntu/50452313#50452313