# How to configure Firefox to use Oracle Java in XUbuntu 12.04?

Tags: firefox, java

It was ok in the past but something has broken some months ago and my bank client authentication Java applet stopped working. Now I have to reboot to Windows and use it from there. I have installed (and am using for different purposes) Oracle JDK (manually, from official Oracle distribution files) on XUbuntu but I think Firefox Java plugin still uses OpenJDK. How to set up and make sure Firefox to use a specific Oracle JDK?

Comment: Hi - you didnt mention which version of the JDK you use - however, have a look at this to see if this Q&A helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @fossfreedom, I've set up Firefox to use Oracle JDK as follows:

1. I've removed IcedTea plugin. Curiously, `apt-get remove` said it is not installed but Synaptic helped.
2. Then I've made a link with

   `ln -s /opt/jdk/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so ~/.mozilla/plugins/`
3. At this point it was looking like Java plug-in is installed (shown in Firefox's plug-ins list and showing no error pop-ups on applet pages) but it didn't work actually: an animated java logo symbol was appearing instead of applets.
4. Then I've tried to open my banking applet and was asked if I trust Oracle Java. After confirming this Java applets began to work fine on all the pages.

Unfortunately this haven't solved my actual problem - banking still doesn't work (fails to log-in with correct key file and password).