# Trouble installing Java due to "./install.sfx: not found" error

Tags: installation, java

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I wanted to install Java and so I downloaded the 32-bit self extracting .bin file from http://www.java.com and tried to install it according to their instruction.

First I made the file an executable one. Then created /usr/java/. After that I have to run this command: `./jre-7u<version>-linux-i586.bin`.

But I'm stuck here. My Java version is Java 6 u32. When I enter the command it says "no such file or directory". What to do? Please help. Also I'm trying to install 32-bit Java on my 64-bit Precise. Could that possibly be the problem?

I tried to follow second answer by Jonas Christensen. I tried to open it, it says file is an unknown type. I tried the terminal command: `./jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin`. But it gave this:

```
Unpacking...   
Checksumming...   
Extracting...   
./jre-6u32-linux-i586.bin: 86: ./jre-6u32-linux-i586.bin: ./install.sfx.5736: not found  
Failed to extract the files. Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please see the "**bug**" described at: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6500693

Resolve by installing 32 bit libs:

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 , instead of `ia32-libs`, I installed `lib32z1`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I used ```lib32z1```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method to install Oracle Java 7 via PPA:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

   - [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

---

See also:

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)
- [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)
- [How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6)
- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need a specific version of java for a special purpose, download the now-latest 7u7 version as a tar file: [*download 7u7 from java.com*](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en) | [*download 6u35 from java.com*](http://java.com/en/download/manual_v6.jsp).

Note that *6u35* link is a bin file as yours. But I have just tried to run it and it works. It is a generic shell script so to execute it: `sh jre-6u35-linux-x64.bin`. It wouldn't break anything that runs on 6u32, so download it with comfort.

Extract the archive and put contents to any directory you want (*chosing a directory like* `/opt/java` *or* `/usr/local/java` *is ok. put it somewhere that you won't accidentally remove*) and keep a note of the full path to that directory. Then edit as needed and put the following code into an executable .sh file inside `/etc/profile.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# You may put this in /etc/profile.d/java.sh

if [ -d <full-path-to-java> ]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:<full-path-to-java>;
fi

# dont forget to make executable, run following in your terminal:
# chmod +x /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

As a little note, don't keep the '<' and '>' characters in  :)