# Need Java for browser

Tags: installation, 12.04, java, internet, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I was surfing this site and it said I need Java installed. When I searched a bit, I found three  Java type(?). Open jdk, sun Java and Oracle. I want to know the difference among them. I need Java for surfing the Internet only, the type of sites that require Java. I tried to install Sun Java but couldn't. Which Should I install & how? If it's Sun Java could you please suggest another method to install? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Install the icedtea plugin an alternative to the java plugin.

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

Differences? Not enough to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to install Oracle Java 7 via PPA:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

---

See also:

[How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

[How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

[How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6)

Comment: can I install open jdk 6 along with Oracle Java 7?