# I need help installing Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I recently dual booted Ubuntu and Windows Vista on my laptop and everything is running smoothly. The only problem is I am unable to install Java (I have no clue where to even start). I am completely new to Ubuntu so be specific if you may. I have already installed the JDK Runtime Enviroment or whatever from the Software Store or whatever Ubuntu calls it. Nothing has worked. If you are wondering, I want to play RuneScape on Ubuntu.

Comment: Some of this will apply: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracles-jdk-6/135894#135894

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, click here:

[OpenJDK](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-7-jre) and install the Web Browser plugin farther down the page.

I was able to install the java plugin (icedtea) at this link from oracle.

[Verify Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp)

It'll have a popup at the top of the window saying it needs additional plugins for this content.  It'll install and then your good.

Comment: Love you man. I'll check that out tomorrow as I'm on Vista at the moment.

Comment: Yo, it didn't work.

Comment: What happened when you went to that sight?

Comment: Nothing, all it did was tell me that something went wrong and Java didn't work.

Comment: Or better yet, open the software center and install OpenJDK and the icedtea addon

Comment: I did earlier already. Nothing.

Comment: no errors or anything?

Comment: No, RuneScape just continued to tell me that Java was not installed. I did that before I made this post.

Comment: and when you went to the verify java page it didnt ask to install it?

Comment: No it just loaded up the page and nothing happened. I waited, got a drink, stared at the screen....nothing.

Comment: and that link I added, what happens there?  Should open your software center.

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and do this

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

All the best,