# How to install sun java 6 jdk and jre to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6)

For Hadoop, I  should install sun-java6-jdk and jre to my Ubuntu 12.04. But, I could not manage to install. How can I install it to Ubuntu 12.04 ?

Note : In http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/sun-java6-jdk/, there is deb file. But, I could not install sun-java6-jdk and jre via apt-get .

Comment: sun java 6 is dead - have you tried oracle java 6 jdk? http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6