# Alternative shades $PATH?

Tags: paths, alternative

I've install jdk now with [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/89098/94519) reference. According to that I have to add jdk directory to PATH variable and add an alternative via `update-alternatives`. I've done that and everything is fine. But there is one thing that is not clear for me: when I type `which java` bash returns only `/usr/bin/java` but tells nothing about `usr/bin/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin` despite this folder is in the PATH variable and as I see, bash should have find `java` also there and mention it in the output. Can anybody explain why there's such a "shade"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is actually a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java`, which is itself a symlink to the actual `java` binary.  The `update-alternatives` script changes where `/etc/alternatives/java` is linked to.  By running `update-alternatives`, `/usr/bin/java` will end up symlinked to `/usr/bin/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java`.

The reason `which java` returns `/usr/bin/java` is that `/usr/bin` is on your `PATH` before `/usr/bin/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin`.  If you run `which -a java`, it should show you both `/usr/bin/java` and `/usr/bin/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin/java`.