# How to install Sun Java jdk 6 on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Oracle JDK 6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6)

The issue has been posted in various sites, but didn't get any of them working for me. Who can help me?

I followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java for Java 6.

Ubuntu version 12.10

1. Downloaded jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin
2. chmod u+x jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin
3. ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 1: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open html: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 2: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open head: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 3: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open title: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 3: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: Request: not found
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 4: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open META: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 5: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open link: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 6: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open link: No such file
   : not foundlinux-x64.bin: 7: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 8: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open body: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 9: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open div: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 10: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open table: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 11: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: cannot open tr: No such file
   ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: 12: ./jdk-6u37-linux-x64.bin: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

What else should I do to get this working? I'm pretty new to linux world. My project requires JDK 6x rather than the latest 7.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to to do it. Just add the webupd8 ppa and run oracle-java6-installer.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

The complete instructions are here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/oracle-sun-java-6-installer-available.html

If you want to install openjdk instead of oracle/sun, run

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```