# Ubuntu 12.04 problem installing thinkorswim

Tags: 12.04, java, openjdk

I have follow the instructions listed in the forum as well as the thinkorswim website. I can get all the way to the launch point for showing the desktop and it won't show I just get a black screen and it freezes on showing desktop. I think it has to do with one either the java I am running or so have said I need to get the thinkorswim tech support to disable the splash start up screen.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Is your question about Java Virtual Machine? May be, you need to [switch it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6/89080#89080)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem under Fedora and Gnome Shell. The main Thinkorswim window didn't show up, and looking at `top`, Java and Xorg used up all CPU.

I managed to properly run Thinkorswim after switching to Openbox as a window manager. My guess is that any non-compositing window manager will do.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue, I approached the thinkorswim tech support and received these instructions which worked for me:
Linux java 7 and tos install instructions

Before installing think or swim you will need to install Oracle Java 7. One  way to install it by adding the Webd8 PPA.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

First:

1. First Install WEBUPD8

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   ```
2. Run the next command

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Run this command to install java

   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

   Download Think or Swim

   You will need to download  think or swim  Linux version from the link below.

   http://mediaserver.thinkorswim.com/installer/install.html
4. You will need to download the thinkorswim_installer.sh  and save it to your downloads folder.
5. Open the Terminal  and Change to the Download Directory using the  cd  command
6. To run think or swim installer type the following command  sh thinkorswim_installer.sh