# Unable to install jdk 6 after uninstalling jdk 7

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

Want to install fresh jdk 6 for Android development. Before I had jdk 7 installed which I removed for fresh jdk 6 installation. Tried using the webupd repository way, not of use, tried downloading the jdk from oracle and then unzipping it, not of use.

I want to know if removing these listed packages will help?

```
java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jre
* gcj-4.6-jre-headless
* openjdk-6-jre-headless
* gcj-4.5-jre-headless
* openjdk-7-jre-headless
 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

#### EDIT: in response to MrVaykadji :

I tried doing the commands ... after i executed the `sudo apt-get install -----` I encountered this error message at the end of log:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java. 
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/ControlPanel to provide /usr/bin/ControlPanel (ControlPanel) in auto mode. 
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-6u38-linux-x64-rpm.bin/java': Not a directory 
dpkg: error processing oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed  post-installation script returned error 
exit status 2 
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already 

Errors were encountered while processing: 
 openjdk-7-jre-headless
 openjdk-6-jre-headless
 default-jre-headless
 openjdk-6-jre
 default-jre
 openjdk-6-jdk
 default-jdk
 openjdk-7-jre
 oracle-java6-installer 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: There is a nice guide on how to it -----   http://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6

Comment: Those packages contain java but are not installed on your system, you will need to install one of those packages to install java; but those are openjdk java(s), not oracle, so may or may not be what you exactly want.

Comment: can u please suggest me how to install those packages...Thanks

Comment: You must have broke something while uninstalling java7, I don't see any other explaination.

Answer (score 0):

This sould be enough :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

If you encounter problems, edit your main post and leave a comment here ;)

Regarding your `java -version` output, the packages aren't installed yet, that's why Ubuntu tells you to install one of them.

Comment: Installers for [Oracle Java 6 does not work](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html) anymore. The download page has been moved and the `apt-get` cannot download the files from the Oracle servers. -- If you really need java 6, you can [download the installers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html) and/or use install [the `oracle-java6-installer` package](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html).