# How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?

Tags: java, jdk, oracle, jre

If I downloaded the [latest JDK from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html), do I just download the `.tar` file and extract it to `/usr/lib/jvm/`?