# Will Sun's Java be available from Canonical's partner repository?

Tags: java, minecraft, openjdk

I just discovered that Oracle's (Sun's) Java6 has vanished from the Canonical's partner repository.

Before Java was taken from all repositories I had purchased Minecraft for play in Ubuntu. After recent re-install I can not find a way to play this game in the only OS installed now on my systems.

Open source Java equivalents will not run this piece of software nor am I able to use Yahoo Games with my friends. Somewhere I should have been given a choice as to what security risks I'm willing to deal with in order continue to use or not use paid commercial software.

Is there any solution besides directly downloading the java from sun and trying to re-install manually? This method coupled with my short Ubuntu term skills is not an option.

Answer (score 17):

Sun Java [has been disabled](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes/Java6Transition) via a security update due to it [exposing users to known security holes](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57335639-263/update-java-to-thwart-active-cross-platform-exploit/) and has been removed from the partner archive.

> Due to the severity of the security risk, Canonical is immediately releasing a security update for the Sun JDK browser plugin which will disable the plugin on all machines. This will mitigate users' risk from malicious websites exploiting the vulnerable version of the Sun JDK.

As such people are strongly encouraged to either install OpenJDK or Oracle's JDK for their Java needs. **Third party PPAs that distribute "sun java" earlier than update 28 are also vulnerable, and should not be recommended for any kind of use.**

This page has a more detailed explanation of the issue:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes/Java6Transition

And you can find information about Java in the official documentation:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

To install OpenJDK follow these instructions:

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java-jdk)

and here are instructions from this site if you want to install Oracle Java:

- [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-jre-7)
- [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-7)

Answer (score 5):

1) Oracle JDK will not longer be released or supported with Oneiric, OpenJDK will be used instead. You will ofc still be able to manually install it and use it free of charge by downloading it from the Oracle download page.

2) Icedtea will still be used for integration on 11.10 as you can see [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/346234).

Answer (score 2):

You can still install Oracle (Sun) Java JRE manually, by applying this easy how-to: http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java

That way, you don't run risks with unverified PPA's and such.

Comment: Funny that this is the only answer that actually ANSWERS THE QUESTION instead of saying "that's not what you're supposed to do" HELLO PEOPLE! Sun java is REQUIRED for minecraft (at least these older versions.) therefore it is what MUST BE INSTALLED. Saying that even oracle has decided to use the openjdk version doesn't actually fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle, OpenJDK is now the official version of Java.  http://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the

To install in Ubuntu, just type in:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

That'll get everything working for you without problems.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Sun Java in 11.10 by using partner repository from 11.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ natty partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-plugin
```

It works fine in FireFox and Opera. The version is `Java 6 update 26`. On http://java.com there is a newer version -- update 27.

---

Edit: Since then I am using an excellent shell script, which automates retrieval and installation of the Oracle (Sun) Java Runtime Environment. It is [provided by Duinsoft](http://duinsoft.nl/packages.php) as a package `update-sun-jre`:

> Updater/installer for Oracle's (Sun) Java Runtime Environment
>    This package will download the Oracle Java Runtime Environment (JRE), which
>    includes the plugin that enables applets written to the Java Platform
>    specification to be run in Mozilla and other web browsers.
>
> WARNING: Installing this package causes the Java Runtime Environment to be
>    downloaded from http://www.java.com and implies you have read and accepted the
>    Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for the Java SE Platform Products and
>    JavaFX from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/.

All the required info and instructions can be found on [Duinsoft site](http://duinsoft.nl/packages.php).

Comment: This answer no longer applies.

Comment: @Jorge: what do you mean by "no longer applies"? kaimadag said it works fine.

Comment: @kilala This answer is from October, java is no longer available in this manner from the partner repository.

Comment: This worked in february too