# Which java packages do i need to run when installing Aptana?

Tags: 11.10, java

I download the latest [Aptana 3.0.5](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) after reinstalling ubuntu 11.10.

I place aptana in the `/opt/` folder. Upon trying to launch the application it warns me with:

`A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run AptanaStudio3. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/opt/AptanaStudio3/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH`

Is this error occurring because i'm missing Java packages? Previously in 11.04 i had to install a couple different java packages (i forgot which) and it suddenly worked.

What do i need to do to get aptana working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [getting started guide](http://aptana.com/products/studio3/getting_started) for Aptana Studio 3:

> Prerequisites:
>
> Before you install the Release, you should have the following tools installed and working correctly:
>
> - Sun/Oracle Java 1.5.x or later on Mac and Linux. OpenJDK is **not** yet supported.
> - ...

So using OpenJDK to run Aptana is not officially supported.

Personally, when I had used OpenJDK in the past to run Aptana, I had various issues with it. So I don't recommend it.

I would recommend to install the latest Java 6.x to run Aptana. I can't find any info on how well 7.x is supported, but I don't think it would be as well supported as 6.x at the moment.

Problem is that Sun/Oracle Java 1.6 is not available any more in the Ubuntu partner repository for Ubuntu 11.10, like it was for previous releases. The alternatives that I have seen being suggested for installing Java 6.x are:

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to open Aptana using openjdk instead of sun's jre `AptanaStudio -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin`.

Openjdk is the default jdk in Ubuntu. As an option you are able to install Oracle's jdk if you download it from Oracle's website.

Comment: I can't install oracle's JDK anymore with apt-get?

Comment: [Have a look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64515/will-11-10-provide-suns-java6-from-canonicals-partner-repository).