# sun java being dropped 'TBD' but when?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Sun's Java be available from Canonical's partner repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64515/will-suns-java-be-available-from-canonicals-partner-repository)

In this article https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx/ReleaseNotes/Java6Transition I read that java from sun (now from oracle) is going to be dropped from the ubuntu repositories. Our company uses this to enable a java application. Since it's publicly available we're concerned about this.

I tried to find an exact date when it will be 'autoremove sun-java' and java applications would not work any longer. Will there be a warning before such drastic measures take place?

Comment: `TBD` means what is means: to be determined. So the 'when' is unlikely to be answered by anyone on this site.

Comment: Are you aware that only "SUN/ Oracle Java" is being dropped because there is an excellent alternative? The package to be installed is called `openjdk-6-jre`

Answer (score 0):

I read about the same thing on OMGUbuntu here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/java-to-be-removed-from-ubuntu-uninstalled-from-user-machines/.

It seems that they are removing Sun/Oracle Java from Ubuntu because of a bug.
Also they are most likely putting OpenJDK as their official implementation.

So you might not experience problems with your user's computers...

Best of luck...

Comment: I'm sure openjdk will be a good alternative and it's becoming mainstream anyway. But our company uses a java application (maintained by an other company) that will only be 'guaranteed to work' with official sun/oracle java. We

Comment: So we install manually oracle/sun java instead of the repo alternative. OPEN scares dinosaurs bigtime.