# With Java being purged from the repo's, what does this mean for Minecraft?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Minecraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5558/how-can-i-install-minecraft)

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 1 LTS on a separate partition on my HD. Now, I read on Web Upd8 awhile back that Oracle had dropped support for Linux, so Java had to be purged from the Repo's. It didn't affect Ubuntu 11.10 as far as I could see, so it didn't bug me at the time.

Now that I am trying to be a Beta tester for Ubuntu, I noticed that in fact Java was completely gone from the Repo's. Old PPA's weren't recognized, it's not in the software center, etc... anyway, enough dragging this out. What does this mean for games/sites that require Java to run on Linux (Minecraft, Speedtest.net, etc...)

Any ideas how to get it working in 12.04 or are we just officially out of luck till an opensoure alternative comes along? Thanks for any information/help you can provide, if any!
Bye guys!

Comment: I'm not saying everyone plays Minecraft, but Java's only purpose isn't JUST Minecraft, it's also a coding language, a lot of pages on the Internet need it to display properly, etc... Oracle screwed Linux pretty hard on this one.

Comment: it means.. install Java 7 from the Oracle site. http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7 http://askubuntu.com/questions/64515/will-suns-java-be-available-from-canonicals-partner-repository

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz

Comment: [OpenJDK](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/openjdk-6-jre) is still available in the repos. Minecraft works fine with it.

Comment: Yes, but lots of applications do not work with OpenJDK, e.g. Apatana Studio, RSSOwl, JDownloader...

Comment: Can someone tell me how to install the Java version that Aboobacker MK linked? I'm not exactly the Linux expert, so any links that can teach me?

Comment: @Midnight You want this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two routes you can take with this:
Either you take open source port of Minecraft, called Minetest-c55. I should warn you though, it's not as full featured in terms of new features added to Minecraft lately.

Or, you find an unofficial repository for sun-java, which is what Notch recommends for running the real minecraft.

However, you shouldn't - judging by this article - have a problem with this in a default Ubuntu install http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/canonical-reverse-java-uninstall-decision/