# how to install jdk7 for eclipse?

Tags: 11.10, eclipse, jdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

I have installed eclipse using Ubuntu software center,so I need to install JDK 7.
I have visited Java download page but I was confused which package I should take also I don't know how to add this JDK to eclipse?
thx advanced.

Comment: note I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit

Comment: Add that comment information to the question and delete the comment, you can do that by looking for the *edit* link under your message or by pressing [this link](http://askubuntu.com/posts/83397/edit). Another thing, OpenJDK7 is not good enough for what you are doing? Do you really need to install Oracle's JDK??? You should be able to develop programs with Java using the included OpenJDK included on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need the Oracle version of JDK, the easieste option would be installing openjdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

If you really need to use Oracle JDK, you can follow this howto [@WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html). Steps 3 and 4 can be replaced by this commands (and are only needed if you have more than one jdk version installed) in the case you dont want to use the ppa:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
sudo update-java-alternatives -s <name of jdk>
```