# What are the disadvantages of adding the repositories from 11.04 to 11.10?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, java, repository

The reason I'm doing this is to have Sun's java 6 installed (getting updates, etc.)

- In 11.10 Sun's Java was removed from the partner repository.

What do you think are the potential disadvantages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Java 7 from the official tarballs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32124/how-do-i-install-java-7-from-the-official-tarballs)

Answer (score 1):

No disadvantages are guaranteed, but you could easily end up with dependency issues, where one package depends on a different version of a library than another package, so it could mess up your system updates or trying to install certain applications. Regarding Java, as mentionned already, try to follow alternative instructions from blogs to download individual packages from an older version of Ubuntu rather than adding old repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the natty repos you could potentially damage your system, however here are some instructions found at: [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

Comment: Jayo, thank you for the extended explanation. The question is targeted at the DISADVANTAGES of adding an older repository to a newer one. The java is more of an example for something existing in an older repo and not in a new one. Can you please elaborate on the  potential damage?

Comment: You may want to post your detailed answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5567/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk/

Comment: @kilaka to be fair, java was your stated reason for wanting to use an old repo, I said you could potentially damage your system (disadvantage) i then detailed how to solve your java issue so you didnt need to use an out-dated repo and damage your system. you're welcome :)

Comment: "Damage" is a big word. Since the packages' version of Natty are lower than the one in Oneiric, it shouldn't break the whole system.