# Eclipse can't find JDK 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

I've got Oracle JDK 7 installed `javac -version` yields

```
javac 1.7.0
```

and the JRE is installed and enabled in Eclipse > Preferences > Installed JREs (As location: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`)

But trying to change Preferences > Compiler > Compiler Compliance Level shows no options above 1.6.0

I'm a novice to ubuntu... Does anyone have any ideas what I've got wrong? I followed the instructions from [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

Screenshot of eclipse.ini and /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10919879/Screenshot.png

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180555/eclipse-does-not-want-to-use-openjdk-7)? I understand that this question came first but my question has an answer that works.

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit your eclipse.ini file and have to specify your jvm path at there. Read this link http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini. It will help you.

Comment: Hm. Not working with:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10919879/Screenshot-bin%20%E2%80%93%20Dolphin.png

Comment: The path should be upto bin directory only. you have ended path with java. just write path upto bin only(including bin).

Comment: Bugger. I think I'll just use netbeans. Persists after changing to -vm
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/

Answer (score 2):

In case you did not already try this:

when you open a project you need to set the environment.

If the environment was already set as 1.6 previously, then you will need to make a new project with the execution environment as 1.7 and import it.

[image: eclipse environment]