# How to install Eclipse for Oracle Java on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, synaptic, openjdk

I have Oracle Java 7 on my system and want to install Eclipse and make it use Java 7 instead of openjdk.

I installed Eclipse earlier using synaptic but after doing `check updates` it didn't work properly, so i removed it along with residual config.

I am new to linux

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the shortest answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88570/eclipse-cant-find-jdk-7).

It tells you to edit the `eclipse.ini` file so Eclipse can use Oracle's JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java

apt-get update

echo debconf shared/accpeted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections

echo debconf shared/accpeted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections

apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: You could try to be a bit more elaborate what the commands do :)