# which java se to download for linux

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, java, jdk, oracle

1 . i went to oracle site but i don't understand which Java to choose !

Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI 77.71 MB    jdk-8u71-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
Linux ARM 64 Hard Float ABI 74.65 MB -----                                                                         < 1 > ----jdk-8u71-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
< 2 >---Linux x86   154.75 MB-----jdk-8u71-linux-i586.rpm
< 3 >---Linux x86   174.91 MB-----jdk-8u71-linux-i586.tar.gz
< 4 >---Linux x64   152.74 MBj-----dk-8u71-linux-x64.rpm
< 5 >Linux x64  172.9 MB-----jdk-8u71-linux-x64.tar.gz

it wont look clear so even after editing , so please vist the site so as you can understand better .

2 . how do i choose , i don't understand what is ARM ? am using Linux Ubuntu   14.03 64 bit , and kindly tell me how do i set path here in Linux ,

3. also tell me , what is oracle showing by saying
   < 1 >-----Java SE Development Kit 8u71
   < 2 >-----Java SE Development Kit 8u72

i have already done Java on a win platform , require a small help from you all for Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Java and which version of it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98899/how-to-install-java-and-which-version-of-it)

Comment: You need to know your architecture. If it's 64-bit, it's probably x64. Pick the .tar.gz one. But I believe there are easier ways of installing Java.

Answer (score 1):

ARM is not Intel based CPU. It's like Raspberry Pi or Smartphone CPU.
*.tar.gz is source code. If you using Intel or AMD choose x64.