# How to Upgrade Oracle JDK and remove old JDK settings

Tags: java, oracle

i searched and not found [how to upgrade oracle jdk](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20to%20upgrade%20oracle%20jdk) in here. I'm not satisfied with OpenJDK7 because it doesn't come with Java Compiler.

I have  installed and configured Sun Java SDK 6 and I want to upgrade to Oracle JDK 7. I searched ppa's from launchpad an wubp8 but it didn't worked . How can I  upgrade Sun JDK 6 to Oracle JDK 7 and also completely  remove all Sun JDK 6 settings?

I'm very grateful for your answers.

Comment: Go here to the following link:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7

Comment: thank you, i'm very pleased with you. i want to remove all setting and configure Sun JDK 6 and start clearly Oracle JDK.

Comment: can everyone help me??

Comment: To upgrade from Sun JDK 6 to Oracle JDK 7, you will first need to install Oracle JDK 7. Then remove all other versions of JDK on your system. What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm running 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade may cause problems , so its better to do a fresh install.

## Completely remove Open-jdk

just use this simple commands in terminal to remove open jdk completely

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
```

## How to install Oracle-Java

To get an automatically update-able Java from Oracle, you can you use the PPA provided from webup8.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

## Installing Oracle Java manually

**For installing Latest Oracle Java:**

To check ubuntu system architecture installed

```
$ uname -m
```

or

```
$ arch
```

Download the Oracle Java JDK for Linux. Make sure you select the correct compressed binaries for your system architecture 32-bit or 64-bit (which end in tar.gz).It will be downloaded in Downloads folder in home.So first open nautilus with sudo as

```
sudo nautilus
```

and make a folder java under

```
/usr/local/
```

and then folow the following commands:

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
sudo cp -r jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java
cd /usr/local/java
sudo chmod a+x jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

At this point you should have two uncompressed binary directories in /usr/local/java check it by

```
ls -a
```

Now edit the system path file by

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

scroll down to the last and add following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Save and exit and write these commands in terminal to Inform your Ubuntu Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaws
. /etc/profile
```

Now everything is installed just check it by

```
java -version
```

the output must be like

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b40)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Congratulation now its installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow one of the suggested answers in the following Ask Ubuntu question:

[How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

this should be able to update your jdk6 to jdk7.

My version is:
1.7.0_03

Comment: rather than repeating information that can quickly get out outdate - please link to an AskUbuntu Q&A (there are several) and just add the extra information the OP is seeking about "removing" his java version.  Thanks.

Comment: Outdated? I just used this same process less than an hour ago to update one of my machines. I thought his question was asking how to upgrade. However your more than welcome to add the extra info.

Comment: updated your answer - however it still doesnt cover "removing JDK settings"

Comment: Just to be clear he did state, "i searched and not found how to upgrade oracle jdk in here." So thats why I was sharing "customize" steps. But your "update" I guess is better and you can also provide in your update what wasn't cover as well. -Thanks.

Comment: thank you sir.. but it doens't help anything T_T

everybody help me please

Comment: Weird that it does not come with a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-7-jre
```

Here you go to install the latest Java version 8 on Ubuntu, both JRE and JDK:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```