# How to remove Oracle JDK

Tags: uninstall, jdk, oracle

I didn't find any related articles about [How to remove Oracle JDK](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=how%20to%20remove%20oracle%20jdk). There are some related articles but they didn't solve the problem.

I installed Oracle JDK tarball file from Oracle site by following this article [How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7). It was very helpful. But still I don't know what I should do in order to uninstall Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It could be done like this:

1. Remove the link:

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/java"    
   sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/javac"    
   sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/javaws"
   ```
2. Then, remove the package in the `/usr/lib/jvm`:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]
   ```

Note :

- Change [version] with any version number that's contained in jdk
  folder's name, example: `jdk[version] = jdk1.7.0_13`.
- If you are new  to Linux, you should probably get familiar with the manual page. Lot of good stuff from there. Just go to the terminal and type 
  `man update-alternatives`.

Comment: Great thanks, it works! but litle missing manual that must be writted in this case

Comment: Doesn't work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/830244/sudo-update-alternatives-remove-not-working

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and choose an openjdk verion. Delete the oracle jdk files and if you need to uninstall openjdk too, do it with the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: how about symlinks? will it become trash link? how should i do to purge remove all settings and configuration from Oracle JDK?

Comment: apt-get purge will allow you to clean up packages completely

Comment: just write that? or any shell commands i have to write?

Comment: These links point to the chosen Java: /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java and /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac

Comment: thank you sir but i don't understand what you write. actually, i'm newbie in linux. could you explain it? i'm very grateful for your help

Comment: I would not worry too much about remaining configuration files that are left back after uninstalling packages. If you do, run "sudo apt-get install dctrl-tools". After installing dctrl-tools run grep-status in order to find the files and the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the symlinks in bin and wherever you extracted the tarball(it SHOULD be in opt, but i didn't read the previous guide)

Comment: what are the steps? i need them. could you explain them all?