# Two Java JDK version is running in my machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following configuration in my system:

- 2Gb Ram
- 64 bit system
- Linux 12.0.1

The problem is when open the eclipse the system become very slow and if I open chrome it becoming too slow.
And I checked in the system there were two Java version is running 
 1. Java jdk5
 2. Java jdk6

please help to fix this.

Comment: Try `update-alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 0):

- Install more RAM ;)
- Do you mean running in sense of processes?
- Open a terminal and look for the java installations:

  ```
  ls /usr/lib/jvm/
  ```
- Have you used the package manager? Then remove it with the software-center.
- Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk) if you installed from oracle: [

Answer (score 0):

You can use update-alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6.45-oracle/bin/javac" 1
```

and then follow it with a command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

You can refer to the official instruction on installing Java by visiting https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java