# Running "eclipse-inst" file present in eclipse installer is giving an error

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse neon 64 bit from eclipse's official website. I followed the steps mentioned in [How to install Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26632/how-to-install-eclipse), but wasn't able to install eclipse. So, I did some more research and I found [How to Install The Latest Eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04, 15.10](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-the-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10/). When, I run eclipse-inst (the 3rd step in the second link), I get a length error on my screen about which I have no idea. The error that I get is here [error when i run ecipse-inst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3az3.png).

Please help me to find a solution for this problem. I am very new to linux (I had installed ubuntu just 2 days ago). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Actually, I installed 32 bit JDK on my 64 bits OS system (surprisingly I was able to compile and run java programs) and 64 bit Eclipse. Thus, I removed the installed version of java [here's the link on removing java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk) and installed the 64 bit java. Thus, I was able to run the eclipse installer file which was previously giving me an error.