# Uninstall Oracle JRE installed from tarball

Tags: java

I installed Oracle Java using [this wikihow tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

This method involves removing OpenJDK, downloading a tarball, uncompressing it, and moving the binaries to system directories. This means that the application is **unknown to `dpkg`** and **not found by any `apt` command** or other package manager.

I tried the solutions in [Uninstall Oracle JRE installed from tarball](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881776/uninstall-oracle-jde-java) but they do not work for my case, for the reasons explained above.

Comment: Pretty thorough instruction over here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely uninstall Java?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

Comment: it won't work as described there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Oracle JDK](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk)

Comment: Ok guys, this is not the first time I use the forum. this issue is not a duplicate. please read the problem and the way I got there. I already read all the java tagged discussion, nothing will fix my problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: Also it shouldn't be closed imo because Bluue Squirrex self-answered it.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java"    
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/javac"    
sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/javaws"    
sudo rm -r /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_121
sudo updatedb
sudo locate -b '\pack200'
sudo rm /home/pietro/Documents/java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/pack200
sudo rm /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/pack200
```

This is how I managed to get rid of it.