# How do I stop oracle JDK from hijacking PATH and breaking update-alternatives?

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

I installed oracle jdk on ubuntu 14.04. Now I want to toggle back to openjdk:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

But it doesn't work. It seems oracle's jdk somehow keeps adding itself to my `$PATH`:

```
...:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:...
```

I've found and killed `/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh`, but there seems to be a failsafe. The audacity!!

How can I fix this?

Comment: What of the `jdk.sh` in that same location, did you kill that too?

Comment: @George There aren't any other related files there. I've tried searching through /etc but haven't found anything else updating PATH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Oracle JDK](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk)

Comment: This would have been the best way to remove it `sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/java" `

Comment: @George I'd prefer not to actually remove it if possible. I just want to temporarily swap to openjdk and then swap back again. It seems like `update-alternatives` was designed for this.

Comment: Then `sudo update-alternatives --config java` should have shown the the three then you pick from there...

Comment: @George yes, but it didn't so I posted this question here.

Comment: Then add it so you can make it the default...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've selected openjdk using the above `update-alternatives` commands. It doesn't work, because that seems to use symlinks but oracle's jdk is overriding my PATH which takes priority. I don't know how the values are being added to PATH and am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track by removing /etc/profile.d/jdk.csh and /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh. You just have to re-login or reboot so that the PATH changes have effect.