# Check java version without java -version

Tags: java, jdk

I get the following error while trying to compile or run everything that has to do with `java` or `javac`:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file <Zip file open error> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717917/java-se-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm?rq=1) that i should uninstall and install again JDK, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk) it is written that I should know which version of java I have installed on my pc in order to uninstall-it.

To check the version installed i run `java -version` but i get the error mentioned above, how can i check my java version without that command?

I know that i have installed java 8 but i don't know precisely which version it is.

Comment: "I know that i have installed java 8 but i don't know precisely which version it is." Installed how?

Comment: I have about 35 different JREs installed in various nonstandard paths on a Linux server, but I cannot execute java -version as they are owned by other users. I also cannot run apt and most system tools (I do not have su). However I do have read access to each of the "java" binaries. Is there a way to find the java version from the binary itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command for checking your java version:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: Wouldn't `update-alternatives --display java` be simpler and better since OP only wants to “display” available Java versions, not change the default? That wouldn't even require `sudo`.

Answer (score 6):

To show what version of Java is installed without running `java -version`, open the terminal and type:

```
apt policy openjdk-* oracle-java*
```

A small part of the results of `apt policy openjdk-*` looks like this:

```
openjdk-7-jre-lib:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
openjdk-8-jdk:
  Installed: 8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 8u162-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
```

Search for sections that contain either `openjdk-*-jre` , `openjdk-*-jdk` or `oracle-java*` where the wildcard `*` character can be a Java version number like 6, 7, 8 or 9.

Comment: thanks, with that command i got tons of lines which one should i search for?

Answer (score 5):

You can discover the full path of the default `java` executable with:

```
readlink -f "$(which java)"
```

All (sane) Java packages or bundles that I know use installation path names that include the vendor name and major version number which would answer your question. E. g. on my system

```
$ readlink -f "$(which java)"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

tells me that the default Java installation is OpenJDK 9.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try:

```sh
dpkg -l | egrep -i 'jre|java|jdk'
```