# Error trying to install JDK 14, would not let me uninstall or reinstall, deleted the whole jvm folder

Tags: apt, java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

downloaded and ran deb file for latest jdk, pc crashed midway. restart and try again, says file not supported. ran java -version, says I have jdk 11. ran sudo apt install default-jdk, says "The package jdk-14.0.1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." Same message occurs when attempting to remove jdk. Found the jdk 14 folder in usr/lib/jvm, deleted. Same message. removed entire jvm folder and did a reset. java -version returns 'java' not found and tells me how to install it, haha, ofcourse, this does not work as, "The package jdk-14.0.1 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Comment: May I suggest you to follow the steps of the accepted answer here, and try re-install the JDK from you .deb file ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk