# How to Install JDK 1.7 using a RPM package?

Tags: installation, java, jdk, jre

Edit `Start`

I have had eclipse running for a while now. And have been developing a java based server.

Edit `End`

Today, eclipse, java project, right click, properties, java build path (jdk 1.6) is suddenly reporting missing jars `(netx.jar, plugin.jar and gnome-java-bridge.jar). May be after a ubuntu auto update these jars went missing. It has also happened to my laptop a few days back.

`java -version`

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.10.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

I could not find anyone else having a similar issue, so I thought I'll upgrade to 1.7. So I downloaded 1.7 jdk and jre from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1637588.html)

I ran the following, on my Ubuntu 10.04

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
sudo alien jre-7u5-linux-i586.rpm
sudo alien jdk-7u5-linux-i586.rpm
```

Unfortunately both report errors. These folders do exist in the path.

```
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 9
find: `jdk-1.7.0_05': No such file or directory


make: *** [binary-arch] Error 9
find: `jre-1.7.0_05': No such file or directory
```

Now when I try to install again, using `sudo alien jdk-7u5-linux-i586.rpm` 
I get

```
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package jdk: postinst postrm prerm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
mkdir: cannot create directory `jdk-1.7.0_05': File exists
unable to mkdir jdk-1.7.0_05:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257.
```

Comment: In addition to clarifying **what** it is that you are asking, please also include more information about what Eclipse says is missing, including the complete and exact error messages you are getting in Eclipse. The errors you did provide are not reporting missing *jar* files. Please also provide the exact commands you run to produce those `make` errors (unless they are occurring *in* Eclipse). Please tell us how you installed Eclipse, and the output of `which java; java -version` in the Terminal. You should **edit your question** to provide all this information.

Comment: @Siddharth - please look at one of the answers here and reinstall JDK with the suggestions there.  Thanks. http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7?rq=1

Comment: This helped to a great extent. Unfortunately I have fallen into one more pit, I am seeing this error now, and nothing I do is fixing it. Will report back once I fix it. Thanks again. "Resource Description Path Location Type
carPoolLibrary The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project  Unknown Java Problem"

Comment: Surprisingly, 1.7 is throwing weird errors, and now when I switch back to 1.6 everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a little bit confusing: you want to know how to patch this Eclipse behaviour or you want to update Java?

The title says 1 thing, the question says another.

If you just want to start eclipse using a specific version of a particular JVM you just have to open the file `eclipse.ini` in the same folder where the eclipse executable is and add this 2 lines:

```
-vm
/home/user/jdk/bin/java
```

This option is pretty self explanatory, you just use the -vm option and specify the full path of your jvm of choice.

If you want to install java from a package downloaded from the internet you need another guide, please be more clear.

Comment: thanks, I now understand where I am confusing people.. I'll edit one more time

Comment: @Siddharth go to the official JDK website from Oracle, download the **.bin** version of the jdk of your choice, open a terminal and execute that **.bin** file just like that `./jdk.bin`, the jdk will be unpacked in a folder named with your jdk version, use the java executable in this newly created folder like i wrote before and try this way.

Comment: Where can I find that .bin file. I dont see it in the list of downloads http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html

Comment: they probably changed the distribution system, but it's the same logic once you have downloaded the file with the JDK, in this case download the tar.gz version and unpack it with the file manager. In the JDK 6 there is the bin, in the version number 7 they probably switched to this tar.gz.

Comment: I think you mean "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" right ?

Comment: @Siddharth about what? These days you do not need to "install" the JDK, it's already compiled and ready for use when you download it as an archive, just unpack, tell the eclipse.ini to use that JVM and you are good to go.