# Install openjdk-7-jre without prompt

Tags: apt, java, openjdk

During the install I have to hit [ENTER] in order for the install to proceed on the command:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Is there a way to avoid this prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but still not answered and relevant. You need to install the headless package instead. At the time of this writing version 11 is out so I am using that as example:

```
apt install -y openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

or for JDK

```
apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the -y option i.e. apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jre

from the apt-get manual:

-y, --yes, --assume-yes
           Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held package, trying to install a
           unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Edit:
To accept the java license, the solution is here:

[Installing Java Automatically (With Silent Option)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190582/installing-java-automatically-with-silent-option#)

Comment: That doesn't work for that one, the prompt you ask for is from `apt-get`. It's during the installation that something pop ups.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this

```
apt update
apt upgrade 
apt install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless
java -version
```

[image]