# Why is this apt configuration necessary for installing Java on vagrant?

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, vagrant

Here is my bootstrap.sh

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections

# Update apt sources
apt-get update

# Install stuff available through apt-get
apt-get install -y unzip wget oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

I am trying to understand why is these two lines

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
```

necessary for installing Java.

According to ubuntu manual,

```
add-apt-repository 

is a script which adds an external APT repository to
   either  /etc/apt/sources.list  or a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ or
   removes an already existing repository.
```

but should't the apt repository be automatically updated, when you

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get install -y oracle-java7-installer
```

?

And what does

```
echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
```

do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: And also: http://askubuntu.com/a/190674/158442, and the easy way in http://askubuntu.com/a/55960/158442

Answer (score 0):

It seems this bootstrap.sh is part of this vagrant which requires that you have Oracle Java7 is installed. So it is making a check and if not echoing it and then taking a particular action(install Oracle Java7). It's using the standard ppa for Oracle Java7 install.