# Replacing the OpenJDK with the Oracle JDK

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, oracle, icedtea

I've had the archive file for Oracle's JDK for some time and have been running java applications through `~/Downloads/jdk1.7.0/bin/java -jar <jarfile>` for some time, but I'm wondering if there's an actual way to "install" the JDK without running through the fiasco with apt-get that I ran into with a previous installation. Also, can I point IcedTea's Applet launcher to the Oracle VM vs the OpenJDK one?

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7/55960#55960

Answer (score 3):

Follow [these instructions](http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php#repo) to add the source to your repositories.

In a terminal run:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install update-sun-jre`
- `sudo update-alternatives --config firefox-javaplugin.so` and select the one that's in `/opt` (This enables Sun Java in Firefox)

With this package you don't have to worry about constantly checking for updates. The maintainer takes good care to keep it current for you. It also adds all the update-alternatives links for you, so it's a lot less work than the above comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Emre ;). Sometimes I get all excited and type too fast for my own good.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux for a complete step by step solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.