# "ERROR:Could not find java.nio.file.Paths" when using Oracle JDK 1.7

Tags: jdk, oracle

I want to try out some features rolled out in Oracle's new JDK 1.7. I followed the post:- [Oracle JDK 1.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) but the post doesn't seem to help.

I was trying to fetch out the structure for `java.nio.file.Paths` class file but got the following error:-

```
buffer@ankit:~$ javap java.nio.file.Paths ERROR:Could not find java.nio.file.Paths
```

However i can easily get the information about class structures till JAVA SE 1.6, here is an example:-

```
buffer@ankit:~$ javap java.lang.Object
Compiled from "Object.java"
public class java.lang.Object{
    public java.lang.Object();
    public final native java.lang.Class getClass();
    public native int hashCode();
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    protected native java.lang.Object clone()       throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public final native void notify();
    public final native void notifyAll();
    public final native void wait(long)       throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
    public final void wait(long, int)       throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
    public final void wait()       throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
    protected void finalize()       throws java.lang.Throwable;
    static {};
}
```

Running java -version gives the following result:-

> buffer@ankit:~$ java -version  java version "1.7.0_09" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

SYSTEM INFORMATION

```
buffer@ankit:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for buffer: 
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09/                        1         manual mode
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/java                1         manual mode



buffer@ankit:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/javac            1         manual mode



buffer@ankit:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
There are 3 choices for the alternative javaws (providing /usr/bin/javaws).

  Selection    Path                                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws   1060      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/javaws                1         manual mode
```

The directory structure of `/usr/lib/jvm/` is as follows:-

```
buffer@ankit:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     24 Dec  2  2011 default-java -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Nov  8 16:24 java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     24 Dec  2  2011 java-1.6.0-openjdk -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     20 Oct 25 00:01 java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-6-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     20 Oct 25 06:59 java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     24 Dec  2  2011 java-6-openjdk -> java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   4096 Nov  8 16:24 java-6-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Nov  8 16:24 java-6-openjdk-common
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 Nov  8 05:48 java-7-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Nov  8 05:48 java-7-openjdk-common
drwxr-xr-x 8 buffer buffer 4096 Sep 25 09:08 jdk1.7.0_09
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you similarly done a `update-alternatives` on `javap` ?

Comment: @fossfreedom, +1, i made changes to java,javac and javaws. I made similar changes to javap and it works :). You can please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### java executable

Java consists of many individual executables - `javac` and `javaws` are the most common.

`javap` is another - when installing Java you need to individually ensure that each executable has been registered - you do so with `update-alternatives`

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "javap" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javap" 1
sudo update-alternatives --config javap
```

This answer gives you a list of the individual executables that you can register if you wish to use them during development.

- https://askubuntu.com/a/68227/14356

Alternatively - you could use a third-part PPA such as `webupd8` - but as a developer myself, I like to understand the issues and tailor my configuration to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Install it through this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html